# How to solve - IOERROR : Fatal Error: File 'path/to/file' could not be located or is not readable

Tags: python, nlp, ioerror

I have been trying to open a file by passing it as an argument. 
I have been providing the correct file path and the file is also readable.

I created another script in order to determine whether the file is readable or not. I got the contents of the text file which shows that the file is readable and the path is also correct.

here is the piece trying to read the file -

```
try:
    with open(args.filepath, "r") as file:
        data = file.read()

except IOError:
    print("Fatal Error: File "+args.filepath+" could not be located or is not readable.")
    exit()
```

The file should be readable in the first place.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? does your code behave not as expected? you can create a test file and run your script and give it that known filename because you will know that (a) the file exists and (b) you have the read permissions on the file

Comment: It is likely that the interpreter is not looking for the file where you think it is looking. For example, if your command line specifies a relative path, then the current working directory may not be what you think it is. But it is hard to tell, because the `except` clause in your code is suppressing the reason given by the operating system. Change it to `except IOError as details:` and add `details` to your `print` call.  Then, if that doesn't tell you what is wrong, edit your question to report the error message that you see,

Comment: Also your except block is worse than useless - it doesn't do anything more than what would happen without it (an unhandled exception WILL terminate the process), and hides potentially useful informations (the exact error message and errno, the full stack trace etc).

Comment: Thanks BoarGules, Your solution worked, pls do comment the link of any documentation regarding your solution or if you could provide an explanation for the difference between your code and my code.

Comment: Pls. do upvote if you found the question valid.